# How to edit default django home page and new page

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, python-3.6

I am beginner to Django. I just install the django & there is default home page appearing. I want to edit the default home page content & create new extra pages. Please can any one help me how to add the new pages with using the template.

Comment: As @Debdut Goswami has answered to you is enough to start rolling with it, but I would suggest you to learn more about templates and how you can manage views, since you can have also class views, template views and even also API views with Django React framework.

Comment: @AlejandroVicaria is right. I understand you are a beginner, so I am recommending one 4 hr long YouTube tutorial which is just awesome. Even I started learning from this [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5mRW0jo-U4&list=WL&index=5&t=0s).  Hope it will guide you well.

Comment: @AlejandroVicaria Thanks for you comment. I am able to create new pages according to my requirement. Now, I need to implement the template & used them accordingly. If you have any tutorial reference please provide me.

Comment: I won't provide you a 4 hr long tutorial like Debdut did... because I find boring to be 4 hrs looking things, I'd rather let you explore, here's a short tutorial  explaining how templates work in Django. [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9elKTmCEhY) With that you should be able to start developing your skills with templates.

Comment: @AlejandroVicaria Thanks for your video link. Now I am able to use the Django templates. Again I want to thank you so much for your support & video links.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start a new application  known as `pages`, this will actually create a directory named pages in the root of your project. Then go to the `views.py` file and add something like this:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def home_view(request,*args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello World</h1>")
```

After this go to the main project folder under which there is a file named `urls.py`.
Edit the file and change it to the following:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from pages.views import home_view, about_view, contact_view
from products.views import product_detail_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('home/', home_view, name='home'),
]
```

Then go to `settings.py` and there you will find a `list` named `INSTALLED_APPS`. Just change the list to the following:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # own
    'pages',
]
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Debdut Goswami, I am now able to create new pages.

Comment: @Shamsi786 I am glad I could help.

Comment: @DebdutGoswami - I'm using pythonanywhere.com to host my app, and in the free version it allows me to have only 1 app (the main project app). So can I edit the home page of the main project app instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Answering myself... Yes it's possible. I added a new dir in main project, and inside it `__init__.py` and `views.py`, and in the main `urls.py` add `from new_dir import views`, and add to `urlpatterns`: `path('', views.home_view, name='home'`). **And reload the server.**

Comment: In my case, apache needs to be restarted for the changes to be applied.

Comment: @Majidkhalili Apache should only be used in production server where it actually makes sense to restart it. For local development, use `python3 manage.py runserver`

Comment: @DebdutGoswami you are right, I forgot to mention it was in the production.